# Create dynamic textboxes using javascript or jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, button, textbox

I don't know what is it called(new in programming)but I need to make 1 TextBox and 1 Button that if user enter any number in TextBox and clicks the Button, TextBox will display depends on the number entered in TextBox for example user entered 5 in TextBox after clicking the button 5 TextBox will show

```
<table style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="300" style="text-align:left"><asp:Label ID="lbres1" runat="server"                            Text="Address"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td width="300"><asp:TextBox ID="txtres2" class="basetxt" runat="server" Width="290"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left"><asp:Label ID="lbres3" runat="server" Text="Number of House occupant"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtres4" class="basetxt" runat="server" Width="290">  </asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left"><asp:Button ID="btnAddOccupant" runat="server" Text="+" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbres5" runat="server" Text="Add Occupant"></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

should I add 1 TextBox and c# or jquery will do the rest?

**It's inside the jquery dialog box btw**

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about _cascading textboxes_ a search on that term would likely help.

Comment: so its called `cascading textboxes` thanks dude i don't really know what is the exact term for this

Comment: you mean you want to create number of textboxes based on user's input ? Let's say user enters 5 and click on the button then 5 new textboxes should be created. am I right ?

Comment: @SpiderCode yes sir can you give me an example code

Comment: @Newbie : I have provided my solution. Hope it is useful to you and you like it. Don't forget to up vote and mark it as an answer so that it may help other developer's as well

Comment: I have a new problem Question Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using javascript or JQuery. Here i am providing you using both JavaScript and JQuery. Please find the below sample for the same :

**Using JavaScript :**

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="buttonCreateTextbox" value="Create Textbox" onclick="CreateText();"/>

<div id="divDynamicTexts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function CreateText() {
        var text = '<input type="text#" id="textInput" value="" /><br/>';
        var textCount = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#textInput').val() ; i++) {
            html = document.getElementById('divDynamicTexts').innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('divDynamicTexts').innerHTML = html + text.replace('#', i);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Using JQuery :**

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="buttonCreateTextbox" value="Create Textbox" onclick="CreateText();"/>

<div id="divDynamicTexts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#buttonCreateTextbox').click(function () {
        var text = '<input type="text#" id="textInput" value="" /><br/>';
        for (var i = 0; i < $('#textInput').val(); i++) {
            $('#divDynamicTexts').append(text.replace('#', i));
        }
    })
</script>
```

> **Note:** Above examples are just sample. You can change it as per your
>   requirement

Comment: can you update this to show div depends on the user enter in the textbox ? because my new project now is to show div depends on the number entered by the user. I have edited the question. Hope you can help me sir

Comment: Dont update question like this. it makes different answer of the question. undo this question amd post new one